# Try-catch doesn't wait for async function inside

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, try-catch

What I'm trying to do is, after retrying to download file for 5 times in case if download was not successful for some reason, to reset the whole process and turn back to first step: function `Try()`. If success, then to proceed `ProcessSet(3);` line

But in my situation, it starts download and without waiting, goes to `ProcessSet(3);` line.

What am I doing wrong? why next steps after `try` doesn't wait for `await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(response.Url), zip_path);` to finish?

Here is the code:

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

    try
    {
        await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(response.Url), zip_path);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(DelayOnRetry);
        Try();
    }
}
SetProgressBar(40, ProgressBarStyle.Continuous);
ProcessSet(3);
```

And here is the `Try()` function

```
private void Try()
{
    ClearFolder(root_dir);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(root_dir);
    main_timer.Enabled = false;
    ProcessSet(1);
}
```

Here is the whole code:

https://gist.github.com/turalus/8c781b5b0c56f66f7ec17e66a3e120fc

Comment: if `Try()` is async method you should use `await`. Also `await` in catch block is available only in `C# 6.0` and above

Comment: You need to post full code, including what is `Try()`.

Comment: @DenisKrasakov actually Try() is main function of app. What I want to do, is if file is not being downloaded for a long time, to restart whole process again.

Comment: @Evk  Try() is main function of app that starts the whole process. And I updated the question. I can include whole application code if you want

Comment: How do you know that "it starts download and without waiting, goes to ProcessSet(3)"? Does that happen when download failed or on success too?

Comment: @Evk it starts downloading file, I see file created with 0kb size and gives error like fille is being used by another program.

Comment: Well hard to say, but at least add `return` after your `Try()` in catch. If you start all process again after error - you don't need to run the rest of the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139349/discussion-between-demonoid-and-evk).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to change retry logic:

```
var isFileDownloaded = false;
var tryCount = 0;
while (tryCount++ < MAX_TRY_COUNT && !isFileDownloaded) {
     using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
     try{
         //do stuff here
         isFileDownloaded = true
     }catch //log exception and Thread.Sleep

}

if (isFileDownloaded){
//        update progress
} else{
//too many retries, exit app
}
```

Comment: updated based on your suggestions. Please review code lines 167 - 198 https://gist.github.com/turalus/8c781b5b0c56f66f7ec17e66a3e120fc

Comment: @demonoid `if (fileDownloaded)` should be outside `while` loop

Comment: `while (tryCount++ < ... `

Answer (score 1):

if you use C# 6+,
make your `Try()` method signature as `async` and invoke with `await`.

Otherwise you need to change the logic with a simple boolean as **@Denis Krasakov** suggested.